# Where is Gulp log file?

Tags: gulp

Running Gulp on a Mac under Docker using Visual Studio Code - the error messages slide into view in a tiny window, and then slide away in about 2 seconds.
It trims off the useful info. I only see about 15 words.
How do I either display the entire message and get it to stay on screen longer, OR where do I find a log of Gulp errors?
Is VSC the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

Right - full error text is shown in terminal window where Gulp was started. The little sliding "now you see me, now you don't" box is very annoying - a perfect misdirection device.